# debug variable passed to python interpreter?

Tags: python, debugging

In a script of mine I am using a Python module and I know I can turn on that module's **DEBUG** prints by just doing:

```
LOGLEVEL=DEBUG python myscript.py
```

I am new to (real) debugging, so this is for sure a stupid question. What's the name of this kind of **variable passing** in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). The value is set and handled by the operating system, and the Python script in question checks the value to determine the granularity of the logging.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is an environment variable used with os.environ dict

```
import os
print(os.environ["LOGLEVEL"])
```